# How to add percent sign to NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, string-literals

I want to have a percentage sign in my string after a digit. Something like this: 75%.

How can I have this done? I tried:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d\%", someDigit];
```

But it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 955, accepted):

The code for percent sign in `NSString` format is `%%`. This is also true for `NSLog()` and `printf()` formats.

Comment: I am trying NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%%", self.Ptextfield.text ] ); and the output is jsut the uitextfield.text

Comment: `NSLog` treats its first argument as a format string, but you have already formatted the string using `stringWithFormat:`.  Just say `NSLog(@"%@%%", self.Ptextfield.text)`.

Comment: This doesn't work for UILocalNotification. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/27971848/2446178.

Comment: this works, this is my case
powerLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Power: %d%%",  power];

Answer (score 140):

The escape code for a percent sign is "%%", so your code would look like this

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%%", someDigit];
```

Also, all the other format specifiers can be found at [Conceptual Strings Articles](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html)

Comment: And the reason why \% doesn't work is that backslash is the escape character for string literals, so typing \% in your source code actually creates a string containing a single percent character.

Answer (score 17):

If that helps in some cases, it is possible to use the unicode character:

```
NSLog(@"Test percentage \uFF05");
```

Comment: `\uFF05` works for me when it is part of the `NSString` in `UILocalNotification`, not `%%`. Thanks!

Comment: That's a "full width percent sign" for use with chinese  or japanese characters, very much different from an ordinary percent character.

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answer doesn't work for UILocalNotification. For some reason, `%%%%` (4 percent signs) or the unicode character '`\uFF05`' only work for this.

So to recap, when formatting your string you may use `%%`. However, if your string is part of a UILocalNotification, use `%%%%` or `\uFF05`.

Answer (score 6):

seems if `%%` followed with a `%@`, the `NSString` will go to some strange codes
try this and this worked for me

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", @"%%", 
                 [textfield text], @"%%"];
```

Answer (score 4):

uese following code.

```
 NSString *searchText = @"Bhupi"
 NSString *formatedSearchText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%%%@%%",searchText];
```

will output: **%Bhupi%**

Answer (score 0):

iOS 9.2.1, Xcode 7.2.1, ARC enabled

You can always append the '%' by itself without any other format specifiers in the string you are appending, like so...

```
int test = 10;

NSString *stringTest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", test];
stringTest = [stringTest stringByAppendingString:@"%"];
NSLog(@"%@", stringTest);
```

**For iOS7.0+**

To expand the answer to other characters that might cause you conflict you may choose to use:

`- (NSString *)stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:(NSCharacterSet *)allowedCharacters`

Written out step by step it looks like this:

```
int test = 10;

NSString *stringTest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", test];
stringTest = [[stringTest stringByAppendingString:@"%"] 
             stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:
             [NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet]];
stringTest = [stringTest stringByRemovingPercentEncoding];

NSLog(@"percent value of test: %@", stringTest);
```

Or short hand:

```
NSLog(@"percent value of test: %@", [[[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", test] 
stringByAppendingString:@"%"] stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:
[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet]] stringByRemovingPercentEncoding]);
```

Thanks to all the original contributors.  Hope this helps.  Cheers!