# How do I output a literal sequence with NSLog

Tags: iphone, cocoa, nslog, literals, escaping

I want `NSLog`to output a literal escape sequence, without treating it as a pattern.

Take, for example `NSLog(@"image%03d.jpg");`, who's output I want to be the actual contents, `image%03d.jpg` instead of `image000.jpg`.

I've tried various escape sequences like `NSLog(@"image\\%03d.jpg");`, `NSLog(@"image\\%03\\d.jpg");` and `NSLog(@"image%03\\d.jpg");`, none of which yielded the expected results.

The problem only grows further when I'm including an actual pattern that I do want to replace, after the literal one: `NSLog(@"image\\%03d.jpg test %d", 1);`, that I'd like to output `image%03d.jpg test 1`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739682/how-to-add-percent-sign-to-nsstring

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use **two** `%%` characters and you will get the desired results:

```
NSLog(@"image%%03d.jpg");
```

Comment: @luvieere I didn't get the accepted answer yet, maybe you forgot?

Comment: There was a time span that I couldn't award the accepted answer for - a several minutes system limit. No worries, ticked it now ;)