# % sign in string objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

i am wondering how i do a % sign within a NSString, i have tried `\%` and `\\%`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add percent sign to NSString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739682/how-to-add-percent-sign-to-nsstring)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try `%%`.

Short question, short answer. :)

Answer (score 4):

just put `%%` to use a % sign within objective c.

Answer (score 4):

There's no special escaping required for percent signs. Just write:

```
str = @"Rate of Return (in %)";
```

...unless you mean *NSString stringWithFormat*. But your question doesn't say so.

Answer (score 3):

According to Apple's 'String Format Specifiers' page, simply use `%%`.

For example:

`NSString * aString = @"50%%";`

Reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html