# NSString stringWithFormat adding a percent

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, stringwithformat

How can I add a percent to my stringWithFormat function? For example, I'd like to have the following:

```
float someFloat = 40.233f;
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f%",someFloat];
```

This should cause the string to be:

```
40.23%
```

But it is not the case. How can I achieve this?

Comment: check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739682/how-to-add-percent-sign-to-nsstring

Comment: The format specifiers can be found at http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html

Answer (score 86, accepted):

`%` being the character beginning printf-style formats, it simply needs to be doubled:

```
float someFloat = 40.233f;
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f%%",someFloat];
```

Comment: what about type double?

Answer (score 13):

The escape code for a percent sign is “%%”, so your code would look like this

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%%", someDigit];
```

This is also true for NSLog() and printf() formats.

Cited from [How to add percent sign to NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739682/how-to-add-percent-sign-to-nsstring).