# how to include a percentage in a string?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NSString stringWithFormat adding a percent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585904/nsstring-stringwithformat-adding-a-percent)

a noob question here.

I have a code:

```
 int value = [sender value];
 [overLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Overhead: %d", (int)value]];
```

and this sets the label as (for example):

```
Overhead: 10
```

I'd like to be able to set it as:

```
Overhead: 10%
```

How do I implement the % into the string so it's not being used to print a value, but it's printed as an actual % character.

thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put two %, like this:

```
 [overLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Overhead: %d %%", (int)value]];
```

Comment: The [String Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265) has all the different format specifiers

Answer (score 2):

You escape the `%` using two `%`.

```
int value = [sender value];
[overLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Overhead: %d%%", (int)value]];
```