# Escape % in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, escaping

I know the %% method, but it's not working :(.

with NSLog

```
 NSLog(@"%%5B hello %%5D");
```

prints

> %5B hello %5D

but with NSString

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%%5B %@ %%5D",@"hello"];
NSLog(str);
```

prints

> 5 hello 68233204

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you left out a line of code. In your `stringWithFormat:` version you probably have something like

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%%5B5%%5D"];
NSLog(str);
```

The problem is you've now doubly-interpreted format characters in the string. Remember, the first arg to `NSLog()` and to `+[NSString stringWithFormat:]` is a format string, where `%` characters are treated specially. In both cases, you can easily preserve the original version of the string (and strip out the duplicate %'s ahead of time) by using actual format strings, as in

```
NSLog(@"%@", @"%5B%5D");
```

Comment: note: calls through NSLog (`NSLog(str);`) should always use a format specification: `NSLog(@"%@",str);`

Answer (score 1):

You do need to use `stringWithFormat:` if you aren't going to pass in any arguments, you should be able to just use

```
NSString *str = @"%%5B%%5D";
```

But as to "why", what you are experiencing is occurring, I am not sure... Try passing in an argument and see if it still happens. Maybe there is a bug when no arguments are passed?

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739682/how-to-add-percent-sign-to-nsstring) post you are escaping it correctly.

[String format specifiers document](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html) says you are doing it right too.

Comment: thank you for your answer :), but I wanted to pass an argument. I've updated my example.