# how can I use % as a character in my NSString?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add percent sign to NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739682/how-to-add-percent-sign-to-nsstring)

Trying to create some string output using the % symbol with no luck:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@% off entire order.",self.discountPercentage.text]
```

Example output would hopefully be something like: 25% off entire order.

Instead I get some crazy output: 25377777777776ff entire order.

Is there an escape character I need to use before the %?

Comment: `NSLog(@"%i%@", 20, [NSString stringWithUTF8String:"% of entire order"]);` also works but is more messy than `%%`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code for percent sign in NSString format is %%.This is also true for NSLog() and printf() formats.

Comment: It looks like you copy-pasted this answer from a duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739682/how-to-add-percent-sign-to-nsstring/739707#739707 If you _must_ do this, please _at least_ give credit to the other answerer.

Comment: No I never saw it. No joke I had it from another app o mine.

Comment: Interesting that they are word-for-word identical, then.

Answer (score 5):

Use `%%` to represent the % characters. (See [String Programming Guide: String Format Specifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1))