# ' % ' symbol was not printing on objective-c

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add percent sign to NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739682/how-to-add-percent-sign-to-nsstring)

I am trying to print `red (10.0 %)` in Objective-C using the statement:

```
    $ newlabel1.text= [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"red (%.1f %)",rv];
```

However, I am getting `red(10.0)` only, and the `%` symbol was not printing. How can I make the percentage symbol print?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should double the percent sign (%%).

Comment: The logic behind this being that in anything printf-derived, % normally combines with the character after it to form a format placeholder. So they introduced %% to output just a %.