# Get special characters in local push notification alert body

Tags: iphone, special-characters, apple-push-notifications, uilocalnotification

I am trying to show the Local push notification with some notify messages to user. But the thing is I can't to show the special characters like `%`.

Comment: This actually isn't a duplicate; he's right. Even if you use the standard NSString stringWithFormat, the percent sign doesn't show up in a local/push notification.

Comment: @elsurudo pls give vote for reopen it!

Comment: No, sorry it was my mistake. It's totally possible. You have to use "%%" in the format string. My problem was that I was using the formatted result as a format string somewhere else, so in fact I have to do "%%%%" to account for the double-formatting. Maybe you're doing something similar, Suresh?

Comment: A now-deleted answer indicates that [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/739707/491960) contains the solution.