# Printing '%' in NSString formatting

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nslog

I need some response like `100 %` but unable to print % after the number, as it comes with warning `incomplete Identifier`.
[image]

I have tried searching solutions, used \%, '%' but no help.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739682/how-to-add-percent-sign-to-nsstring

Comment: I have found that `%%`, while the "right" way to do this, does not always work in all circumstances, and so I just make `'%'` a parameter and format with %c.

Comment: @HotLicks I'm curious - do you have an example where it doesn't work as expected?

Comment: @maddy - Not at hand.  And I was dealing with a lot of "mixed mode" stuff, some `stringWithFormat`, some `printf`, NSLog and other debug macros, et al, so it got pretty hairy trying to keep the exceptions straight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Escape* the special `%` character using another `%` character:

```
@"%2.0f%%"
```

Comment: ... and accurate too! :D

Answer (score 2):

The format specifier for a literal `%` is `%%`.