# NSURL with string %20

Tags: ios, nsstring

I want the url of the webpage of whatever to look something like this:

foo.com/l=english&se=local&incEN=false&q=bob%20bob&

the problem here is that when i say

```
urlString = @"foo.com/l=english&se=local&incEN=false&q=bob%20bob&";
[self initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
```

I want the website url string to be "foo.com/l=english&se=local&incEN=false&q=bob%20bob&" but it is giving me:

foo.com/l=english&se=local&incEN=false&q=bob22520bob&

as the string for the NSURL.

How do I fix this so that I get the desired string to be set as the NSURL string?

Comment: Should you have `?` in the URL (for query parameters)?

Comment: Sho's answer should work. If you want to manually use the % in your string write %% in it's place: http://stackoverflow.com/a/739707/653513

Comment: @rokjarc Sho's answer did not work for me. Please look at my comment on his post. the problem is that I am creating urlString with NSString stringWithFormat...would that make any difference?

Comment: Try replacing `%20` with `+`

Comment: Since you are using `+stringWithFormat:` please include that in the code in your question. It is almost certainly the cause of the bug

Answer (score 2):

Try this function:

```
NSString* urlString = @"foo.com/l=english&se=local&incEN=false&q=bob bob&"
NSString* urlEscaped [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

No need to add %20 in the URL, just escape it in the next function.

Comment: No this is giving me:   foo.com/l=english&se=local&incEN=false&q=bob2ob&     which i do not want. i want the '%' sign to be there after nsurl

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `%20` with `+`.
I often see spaces in URLs encoded as a plain `+` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the url

```
urlString = @"foo.com/l=english&se=local&incEN=false&q=bob%20bob&";
```

is already using some kind of encoding for space as "%20",so using "stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding" method will encode it again which will result as"%22520" for space.Also the encoding method may not work correctly if it is http not https.For me using https instead of http and encoding the url string with NSUTF8StringEncoding worked.