# Adding a "%" in a label without triggering incomplete format specifier

Tags: objective-c

I am making an application that uses a progress bar.I would like to display the percentage of completion, but inserting a `"%"` will interfere with the number that will be displayed.

This is what I have

```
[percentage setText:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Progress: %.0f", progressBar.progress*100]];
```

& I would like to insert the `"%"` at the end of the string. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add percent sign to NSString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739682/how-to-add-percent-sign-to-nsstring)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just escape the percent `%%`:

```
[percentage setText:
    [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Progress: %.0f%%", progressBar.progress*100]];
```

Answer (score 3):

`%%` will give you the percent symbol in your string.