# % character not showing in iOS notification

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, notifications

When I'm trying to display a notification in iOS, the characters "% " get removed.

The text I am trying to display is "51% ", but all I get is "50".

Any ideas why?

I've check in the debugger and put a breakpoint where I see what my message is supposed to say before being sent as a notification and it properly says "51% ", but when it's displayed via notification, it gets chopped off.

Comment: % is often used as a placeholder for value substituitions. Have you tried typical escape patterns such as %% or \%?

Comment: Most likely your notification makes use of some obj-c object (e.g. `NSString`): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739682/how-to-add-percent-sign-to-nsstring

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Might be interpreting the % as a printf formatter. Try using %%, as explained in the `UNNotificationContent` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationcontent/1649863-body) of property `body`:

> If you specified two percent symbols (%%) in the message body, the system replaces it with a single percent symbol (%). The system strips all other printf style escape characters from your string prior to display.

Comment: Be careful, the old `UILocalNotification` API requires you to escape this character, however the new `UNNotificationContent` class does it automatically (you don't need to escape any character). In my personal case, after migrating to the UNNotificationCenter API, the notifications containing the `%` character started to appear with the duplicate symbol because I was escaping it for the deprecated version,

Comment: The `UNNotificationContent` documentation of property `body` clearly states: "If you specified two percent symbols (%%) in the message body, the system replaces it with a single percent symbol (%). The system strips all other printf style escape characters from your string prior to display." (see: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationcontent/1649863-body ). So the comment from @tomacco is wrong and confusing, since escaping is required for `UNNotificationContent`.